# Is there a Nuget package for Mac SQLite.Net PCL Platform (SQLite.Net.Platform)

Tags: macos, sqlite

I see that there's a Nuget Platform implementation for the following

- Win32 - SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32 XamarinIOS -
- SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS XamarinAndroid -
- SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid

But is there one availabe for Mac / OSX?

I'm developing using the Xamarin Studio and wish to eventually write a Mac app too, but to start with I want to write NUnit tests on the Mac and therefore I believe that I need a Mac version?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have not had time to create any more platform implementations.

That said, they are fairly easy to do, you should be able to basically reuse the Win32 class implementation.
The one change you will have to do is to include a Mac/OS X compatible binary of sqlite and change the DllImport statements so that they actually reference that file instead.

The Win32 platform implementation also does some fancy stuff to dynamically load the correct 32/64-bit version of the sqlite binary, using a Win32 function called LoadLibrary.
I'm not sure how this would work of OS X, but I guess there would be an equivalent function you can pinvoke. If you don't want to mess with that just reference the 64- (or 32-) bit sqlite binary directly and make sure the tests run as the same.

If you do go through with this I would love to see a pull request on github:)